# p y manage.py run server not working in vscode editor

Tags: python, django

recently started learning Django  and  not to run this command "p y manage.py run server"

I am using windows 10 and vs code(power shell) as terminal

it's showing me again and again that i have no such file in the directory

Comment: no  in windows "python" term doesn't work. so i use py

Comment: you are clearly missing basic python fundamentionals. of course the python command works on windows if you configured it correctly. you want to run the file manage.py with python. if you dont know how to do that, thats the first thing you should research

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the "python" command on windows, you need to make sure your Python installation is added to your windows PATH. Assuming you have already got Python installed, you need to find its installation directory, usually, it is one of these:

```
C:\Python3x
C:\Users\(Your logged in User)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3x.
```

Next, you need to right-click **This PC > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > New** where the input window pops out with two input fields, namely Variable Name and Variable value. As a variable name, you should type "Path", whereas Variable value should be a valid python path that you acquired in the previous step like so.

[image]

Click OK to save and restart your PC.